# Displaying Mysql Query Results on a Web Page

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code on my site:

```
 $query="SELECT lastname FROM user";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
```

The name of the field I want to show on my webpage is `lastname`, while `user` is the name of the table itself.

The HTML body of my website is:

```
Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['$result']; ?>.
```

This is not working, can someone please assist me.

Answer (score 2):

`$result` will contain just a resource handler. You use that to fetch rows:

```
<?php    
$query  = "SELECT lastname FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row    = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
Welcome <?php echo $row['lastname'] ?>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" in what way? Error messages? Wrong output? too much output?

Answer (score 1):

$result is a "resource", containing the results of the query. However, what you probably want is to loop through all the results (since that query will return the lastname of every row in 'user')

```
$query="SELECT lastname FROM user";
$result=mysql_query($query);


while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== FALSE) {
    echo "The lastname for this row is " . $row['lastname'] . "<br />";
}
```

You should also look into [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Sounds like you've got a problem with your MySQL connection.  Are you sure your database is set up correctly?  Try `$query = "SELECT * FROM user";  $result = mysql_query($query);  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); print_r($result);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things missing here:

1. The query selects all `lastname`'s from the table, not just one. You probably need a query like this (assuming $_SESSION['username'] is where you store their username):

   ```
   $query="SELECT lastname FROM user WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['username'] . ";";
   ```
2. The code does not actually fetch the result set. It just runs the query.  You need to run mysql_fetch_assoc() to get the first row of the result set:

   ```
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   ```
3. You're never setting `$_SESSION['$result']`. You should set a variable like so:

   ```
   $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
   ```

   And echo it like so:

   ```
   Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?>.
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT lastname FROM user WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['username'] . ";";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['lastname']; ?>.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i entered the code above but it is just welcome it nothing beside it

Comment: Don't forget that `$_SESSION['username']` may be a vector for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @sarnold sorry but what does that mean?

Comment: What it means is do not use `mysql_query` and instead use PDO. If you put arbitrary strings in your SQL, people can take advantage of that to [inject whatever they want](http://xkcd.com/327/). Take thirty minutes to read [the PDO tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and you will never have injection problems again.

Comment: @Jacob, an [SQL Injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) is when an SQL query is built as a string using data from an untrusted data source. If a user has the name `O'reilly` you'll come back asking why your code suddenly broke -- but an attacker may take the opportunity to read your entire database, make changes as they see fit, or destroy the whole thing. (The consequences vary from minor to severe based on the _specifics_ of the vulnerability -- but the fix, switching to PDO, is simple and saves time compared to trying to manage safe/unsafe data yourself.)

Comment: @sarnold but why would this effect displaying the result now?

Comment: @Jacob: it might not. But security bugs are best smashed when you first see one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You would do:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT lastname FROM user";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
?>
Welcome <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?>.
```

The array `$row` will contain all the values from the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query will return a resource so displaying it straight is not the right thing to do.
You can better use:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{  
 //echo the relevant fields.
  echo(row[0]); 
}
```

You can also use print_r method to dump the whole of the resource.
Use echo(mysql_error()) if there is some other fault in the code.
You should also read the mysql_query documentation on the php site as it is used a lot.